# change font in plotrix' multhist

Tags: r, fonts, plotrix

Suppose that data is

```
library(plotrix)
set.seed(42)
a <- rnorm(100)
b <- rnorm(100) + 1
```

and I would like to plot these using `multhist()`from `plotrix` and use Palatino font (or any other serif font). Unfortunately,

```
multhist(list(a,b), family="Palatino")
```

yields a standard plot with a sans serif font. Is there a trick to change fonts in `multhist()`?

Comment: which OS are you on?

Comment: I'm using MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotrix calls the default barplot parameters and to change the fonts there, you need to use par. For MacOS, it should be [as described in this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/changing-the-font-of-r-base-graphic-plots/)

Not very good with fonts, hope this is correct:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
par(family ="sans")
multhist(list(a,b),main="sans")

quartzFonts(palatino = c("Palatino Regular","Palatino Italic",
"Palatino Bold","Palatino Bold Italic"))
par(family ="Palatino")
multhist(list(a,b),main="Palatino")

quartzFonts(avenir = c("Avenir Book", "Avenir Black", 
"Avenir Book Oblique", "Avenir Black Oblique"))
par(family ="avenir")
multhist(list(a,b),main="avenir")
```

[image]

So you need to open a new device and do:

```
quartzFonts(palatino = c("Palatino Regular","Palatino Italic",
    "Palatino Bold","Palatino Bold Italic"))
    par(family ="Palatino")
    multhist(list(a,b),main="Palatino")
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks! All I needed to do was add `par(family="Palatino")` to my `pdf(...)` device.

Comment: you're welcome :) glad it's helpful. i can never tell fonts apart from one another